# SpreadsheetGear Column Sum Calculation

Tags: c#, excel

Is it possible to set the Formula on Column First Say "=SUM(A1:A10)" and after that Display the value in A1 to A10 Cells and after that do the calculation.

Comment: interchange first 2 words. is it....

Answer (score 1):

Yes i gets the answer.  While Doing some R N D for that i realized that the Furmula operatiion is **not work with**  :

```
SpreadsheetGear.IRange range = WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A10"];
range.Formula = "=SUM(A1:A9)"
SpreadsheetGear.IRange range1 = WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A1"];
range1.value = "1"
SpreadsheetGear.IRange range2 = WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A2"];
range2.value = "2"
SpreadsheetGear.IRange range3 = WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A3"];
range3.value = "3"
```

**But works with**

```
   SpreadsheetGear.IRange range = WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A10"];
    range.Formula = "=SUM(A1:A9)"             
     WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value="1";
        WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A2"].Value="2";
        WorkBookViewForData.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A3"].Value="3";
```

where WorkBookViewForData is the name of the SpreadsheetGear Control

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use following:**

```
totalCell.Formula = "=SUM(C6,C11,C16,C21)";
```

**Go through following link for detailed code:**

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/srcview.aspx?file=outline.aspx

Hope its helpful.